# How do I prevent this black background from appearing in my UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, uinavigationbar

I have a segue where I transition from a large title to a small title `UINavigationBar` and as you can see, there is a black background showing through when I transition. The table view is the default provided for a `UITableViewController` (no constraints, full screen). It's clear that the problem is the `tableview` is not expanding to fill the available space. How can I fix this?

Code for the transition:
`self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = UINavigationItem.LargeTitleDisplayMode.never`

[image]

Comment: keep the old rule: never ever use UITableViewController

Comment: @sage444 I still get the problem with UIViewController and a constraint to top safe area.

Comment: you could try changing the UITableViewController/UIViewController's background color to white/whatever color you would like the space to be

Comment: Could you provide the part isolated code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further examination of iOS's Mail app, the table view does not resize and instead has set the background of the UIWindow in AppDelegate to match the UITableView. This was my solution.